# IE9 enable searching from address bar

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

In IE9 there is no search box part of the toolbar anymore to search without going to a search page. I want to be able to search via the address bar.

When I was in IE8, I disabled searching via the address bar. This setting has transfered to my IE9. However, now I can't find the option to enable search via address bar in IE9. How do I enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searches are completed via the address bar (its a combo address/search bar), anything typed will use youre default search provider which can be changed via the Tools menu option 'Manage Add-Ons' under the heading 'Search Providers'.

If the combo search function is not working, from the 'Manage Add-Ons' window heading 'Search Providers' verify the check box 'Search in the address bar' is checked.

Comment: Nope, my address bar only works for URLs. Anything other than a real domain name does not work. E.g. blah turns into `http://blah/` (page cannot be found).

Comment: Seems you've lost the default behavior.  From the Manage Add-Ons window under the Search Providers heading verify that 'Search in the address bar' is checked.

Comment: thanks for that! If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @valamas - Edited the answer with the additional troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 1):

Type a question mark in the address bar first to invoke searching.

So to search for "Super Users" you'd type in "?Super Users".  I've found that makes the lack of a seperate search box more bareable. :)